# How can I connect to database my application is using & explore into it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, entity-framework-6

I have created a simple application as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) on `MSDN`, this is simple `Code First` workflow example, this works fine, it stores data and displays stored data as well . But I don't know to how can I access database it is using? And how can I connect to that database to explore into entered data?

Note: I am using EF6 with VS 2013 ultimate

`App.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: there's a section in that article called `Where’s My Data?` that shows you how to see it

Comment: I tried both `(local)\v11.0` and `.\SQLEXPRESS` and it says both of these have not be installed on machine. So how can I know which one is installed? @Jonesy

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection string in the config file.

Now that you added the config try:

(local)\mssqllocaldb or .\mssqllocaldb

Comment: Connection string not found in `App.config.`

Adding `App.config` in question may be that would help you to answer.  
 @user3657925

Answer (score 0):

In `VS 2013 ultimate`
**View->SQL Server Object Explorer**
and there you will find your databases.